# Cisco router telnet troubleshooting - connection timeout; unresponsive host

Tags: cisco, troubleshooting, packet-tracer

I cannot figure out how to establish a telnet connection between two routers in Cisco Packet Tracer. This is a relatively simple process, I know, but I have been back and forth looking for how to fix this issue. At first, I thought I created the ip addresses with a subnet that was too small, but after increasing the size of the subnet from 255.255.255.252 to a standard class C subnet, I've realized that wasn't the problem. I will post the information that is related to this issue to simply your ability to help me. Please help me to understand what I am doing wrong. I will look at resources you post, but please be aware that I've been looking at resources on google for 2 weeks now. There are no users configured for the routers, because I figured that if I can't get the connection to even establish, then logging in is another problem I can deal with after.

When I telnet from router one with "telnet 172.16.3.1", I continue to recieve that the connection timed out and that the remote host isn't responding. It is the same from router2 to 172.16.1.1.

Do I need to set a line to connection from one console port to another or what? I am lost on what to do next. I appreciate all help. I need to do this so I can change the motd remotely. It's a demonstration I am doing for class, and the teacher refuses to help. Please and thank you. I'll update any additional information you feel is necessary to help me.

```
Router1#
fa0/0 172.16.2.1 255.255.255.0
s2/0 172.16.1.1 255.255.255.0

Router2#
fa0/0 172.16.4.1 255.255.255.0
s2/0 172.16.3.1 255.255.255.0

vty 0 4
! for both routers
 password password
 login local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to telnet via the serial interfaces s2/0...

Are Router1 and Router2 connected serially on their respective s2/0 interfaces? Make sure they are. And if they are, the IP addresses you have assigned to them (172.16.1.1 and 172.16.3.1) are not in the same subnet with your specified 255.255.255.0 subnet mask. Either change your subnet mask to something that will encompass both IP addresses (e.g., 255.255.0.0) **OR** change the IP address(es) to the same subnet (e.g., 172.16.1.1 and 172.16.1.2).

Comment: I will try to change the id addresses, since changing the routers to a class B subnet results in the subnets overlappping, so I should realized that I should have altered the IP addresses to avoid that. I'll post the results and let you know if that fixes the problem. I do appreciate your help.

Comment: Both answers were correct, but I haven't remembered to select one until now, so I don't have the results to show, but the answers here are suitable enough. At the time that I read these answers, I still had a little lacking in the understanding of variable subnet masks, and so i didn't completely understand at the time how these answers exactly correct. I ended up on repetitious trial-and-error runs. I realized the differential subdivision of vsm & connected the mental concepts & imaginary math groups together into a working routing network, but it wasn't easy.

Answer (score 1):

Your routers on the f0/0 network are not in the same subnet.  Router 2 should be 172.16.2.2 255.255.255.0  They can only communicate with each other if they have a shared subnet.  I'm also assuming that the ethernet network is the one you're using to connect them.